# Cakephp /Config/email.php into a Plugin

Tags: email, cakephp, plugins, configuration

Hi i have a plugin called Contact and into it i have
    /Config/email.php file.
Cake seems not to load that file.
In my main bootstrap.php file i tried this:

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(array('Contact'=>array('bootstrap'=>true, 'email'=>true, 'routes'=>true)));
```

the bootstrap.php and routes.php file are loaded, the email.php no

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `CakePlugin::load/loadAll()` works, there is no `email` option, only `bootstrap`, `routes` and `ignoreMissing`.

Check the coobook and the API documentation

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#advanced-bootstrapping
- http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-CakePlugin.html#_load

> If you like to load more than one bootstrap file for a plugin. You can specify an array of files for the `bootstrap` configuration key...

So something like this should work for you:

```
CakePlugin::loadAll(array(
    'Contact' => array(
        'bootstrap' => array(
            'bootstrap',
            'email'
        ),
        'routes'=>true
    )
));
```

That would load the files `/Plugin/Contact/Config/bootstrap.php` and `/Plugin/Contact/Config/email.php`.

However it won't work in case that file contains an `EmailConfig` class definition and your app also loads the `app/Config/email.php` file where such a class definition already exists. In that case you should choose another way to define your email configuration settings.